# Apache2 error.log is not showing PHP errors

Tags: php, logging

My Apache2's error.log is in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, yet when I tail it, it does not show any php error or warning, in fact, does not show anything, just this two lines every time I tail the file:

```
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 32683:tid 140320213141376] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 32683:tid 140320213141376] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

What can I do?

Comment: How about `/var/log/php*-fpm.log`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does PHP store the error log? (php5, apache, fastcgi, cpanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel)

Comment: Why do you assume that there should be any more messages?

Comment: - The directory /var/log/php*-fpm.log does not exist.

Comment: -It necessarily has to show errors, because there are.

Comment: Make sure its actually `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Check you `vhost` file